# this.refs.FieldName.focus() is not a function in React Native

Tags: react-native, custom-keyboard, onfocus

I am using Custom Keyboard. In that I am using CustomTextInput in place of TextInput. All works well but I want to focus input field in function.

```
            <CustomTextInput customKeyboardType="hello" 
                    onFocus={() => this.onFocus('fieldname')} 
                    selectTextOnFocus={ true } 
                    ref="TextInput" 
                    underlineColorAndroid = 'transparent' 
                  onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({fieldname:this.onChange(value)})}
            />
```

In Function something like below :-

```
   function () {
     Keyboard.dismiss();  
     this.refs.TextInput.focus();
   }
```

But I am getting an error :- this.refs.TextInput.focus is not a function. 
Basically my focus() function is not working.

Please help!

Comment: check this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9919

Comment: @AliSn I have checked but my requirement is different. I want to focus just after when I click on text input. Basically I am dismissing the default keyboard and opening the custom keyboard. For that I need to call focus function.

Answer (score 2):

I tried `this.refs['TextInput'].focus()` and it works for me. You can write a function for `Textinput`'s `onFocus` and within this function dimiss default keyboard, lunch your customized keyboard and focus again on your `TextInput`. I hope it will help.

This is my code:

```
<TextInput
    style={{ height: 40, width: 200 }}
    ref="TextInput"
/>

<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => { (this.refs['TextInput'] as any).focus() }}>
        <Text>Press to focus</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: This is fixed. Thanks